# Git Flow release version already exists

Tags: git, version, release, git-flow

I know this might be a dumb question but when I try to start a new Release with Git Flow, it says that this release version number already exist.
One of my team member already created a release with this version number, but I would like to override it after some changes in our version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found the solution, with Sourcetree I can force delete the tag for a specific release.